# How to make mutually exclusive Modifiers or Object visivility

Tags: modifiers, visibility

[image]

What I want to do is have several modifiers on an object, like booleans in this case, but have them be mutually exclusive from one another. So if I display one, the others would turn off and vice versa. I've managed to make one modifier's display setting be the opposite of another with a driver but it doesn't seem to work with more than one variable and can't be manually turned on/off either.

Is this even possible to do?
I'd like to do the same with the visibility of objects in a collection as well but I imagine that's a different story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do it with a custom property.

Select an object, an empty for example. Go to Object Properties > Custom Properties and click Add, and Edit it. Set the Property Value to 0 and the Default Value to 1 (so it will only use integers) and set the Min value to 0 and Max value to the number of boolean cutting shapes -1. In your case 2. Click OK.

Then right click the value field next to "prop" (the name of the custom property) and do Copy Data Path.

Now for each of your drivers set the Data Variable Type to Single Property.
As Prop choose your Empty object with the custom property. And mouse hoover over the field next to Path and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> paste the Data Path. It should now say `["prop"]`.

Finally enter for each of your drivers respectively, in the field next to Expression: `var==0` , `var==1` and `var==2`.

[image]

Now if you set the custom property to for instance 2, only the boolean modifier with the driver with the expression `var==2` will show.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I came up with two strategies as a script :

1. Link the viewport visibility to the render visibility and use the render visibility to act as a toggle.
2. Link the viewport visibility to the expanded state of the modifiers and use this as a toggle.

Select the object on which the modifiers are linked and run the following script :

[How to run a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11604548/7092409)

```
import bpy


def main():
    ao = bpy.context.active_object
    if not ao or ao.type != 'MESH':
        print("Select a mesh object")
        return
    for mod in ao.modifiers:        
        add_driver_to(ao, mod, "show_viewport", [m for m in ao.modifiers if m != mod])
    

def add_driver_to(obj_to, mod_to, prop_to, other_mods):
    driver = obj_to.modifiers[mod_to.name].driver_add(prop_to).driver
    driver.expression = ""
    for i, other_mod in enumerate(other_mods):
        name = "mod_" + str(i)
        # Make sure we don't add variables indefinitely :
        var = driver.variables.get(name)
        if not var:
            var = driver.variables.new()
        var.name = name
        var.type = 'SINGLE_PROP'

        target = var.targets[0]
        target.id_type = 'OBJECT'
        target.id = obj_to
#        Solution 1 : Remove # on the following line to link visibility to the modifier's render visbility
        target.data_path = f'modifiers["{other_mod.name}"].show_render'
#        Solution 2 : Remove # on the following line to link visibility to the modifier's expanded state
#        target.data_path = f'modifiers["{other_mod.name}"].show_expanded'
        
        if i != 0:
            driver.expression += " and not "
        else:
            driver.expression += "not "
        driver.expression += name

        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How it works :

Basically, the script adds a driver on each modifier's `show_viewport` property, with as many variables as you have other modifiers. Then it uses simple boolean logic to decide wether it should be visible (ie if no other one is visible at the same time or if no modifier at all is visible)

Solution 1 :

[image]

Note : All modifiers will be visible in viewport if no modifier is set to render, and no modifier will be visibile in viewport if more than one is set to render.

Solution 2 :

[image]

Note : I guess there is no forced update when the modifiers get expanded or retracted so you have to click on something to update the visibility after expanding a modifier. It doesn't have to be on the visibility button but since it is as driver, this will have no side-effect. All modifiers will be visibile if none is expanded and No modifier will be visible if more than one is expanded.